Is there a method to get the last query using mysql2?
I am using nextjs and mysql2 and was wondering if there is a method to get the last query. Below is an example of my code
try {
const [rows] = await db.query('SELECT * FROM stores_new WHERE store_id = ?', [store_id]);
//console.log("Last Query:", getLastQuery());  // Retrieve and log the last query
return rows[0]; // Return the first row (assuming store_id is unique)

}catch (error){
console.error('Database error:', error);
throw new Error('Failed to retrieve store info'); // Throw an error to be caught in handler
}
